# Can anybody recommend a hosting service where security is paramount?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Can anybody recommend a hosting service where security is paramount? We are looking for a VPS or dedicated service that offers hardware based firewalls (i.e. Juniper, Sonicwall), a hardened Linux based environment, software based intrusion prevention services (minimum cfs, mod_sec), and no latency issues. C-Panel based environment preferred. The host should provide the initial server- and security setup, including disabling all unnecessary services, we will rebuild all websites.

Comment: Surely if security is paramount then you can't use a VPS or managed service?

Answer (score -1):

I use hostgator, it's just a very good and big hosting service.
So they probalby have very good security too...

It's also very important to make your site itself secure.

Comment: Being big does not automatically translate in being secure. Minimum security includes ConfigServer Firewall (csf), mod_sec, disabling unnecessary services, etc. We have this now and we have increased default security settings to high, blocked access to the sites on the country-level for some rouge states, enabled temporary-to-permanent-blocking - you name it. We have also minimized the number of plug-ins in WP and disabled services. Nevertheless, we see 5 - 20 attacks per day, including SQL_injection attacks. They result in latency issues forcing us to restart the VPS 2-3 times per day.